# 'Register' extra methods with a base class with automatic discovery

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a base class which will check for a set of common methods and do something with each one if it exists:

```
class BaseClass {

  get router() {
    if (!this._router) {
      this._register();
    }
    return this._router;
  }

  _register() {
    this._router = new Router()
    if (this.list) {
      this._router.use('/', this.list);
    }      

    if (this.detail) {
      this._router.use('/:id', this.detail);
    }
    // etc...

   }

}
```

I want to allow users of the class to 'register' their own custom methods aswell. 
As a first pass, I thought to have them override `_register`:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {      
  list() {...}

  _register() {
    super._register();
    this._router.use('/custom/route', this.customMethod);
  } 
}
```

Hmmm... thats not great as they have to add the `super` boilerplate and know about `_router`.

My next best was to add a method to register extras in the base class:

```
addExtraRoute(route, method) {
  this._extras[route] = method
}
```

Then to loop over it in the _register method, adding them all.
this is slightly better as the user can then just 'register' their methods in the constructor:

```
class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.addExtraRoute('/custom/route', this.customMethod);
    }
}
```

still not great:

- No locality between defining the method and registering, which is a bit harder to read
- Still the super boilerplate & need to make sure we know about any arguments to be passed to the base class.

What is a better design?

Answer (score 0):

There is a common pattern when designing some class hierarchy that is known as "designing for extension". For this reason normally we create some empty (placeholder) methods that are to be overridden by the clients and execute these somewhere inside our lifecycle. Consider the following:

```
class BaseClass {
 constructor() {
    _register(this.getExtraRoutes());
  }

  _register(routes) {
    ...
  }

  getExtraRoutes() {
    return [];
  }
}

class MyClass extends BaseClass {
  getExtraRoutes() {
    return { ... }
  }
}
```

Is it something you were looking for?